# Can separable states display statistical correlations between global observables

Tags: quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, quantum-optics, observables

In the following the notation
$|a\rangle$
represents one single particle in the spin state $a$,
so that
$|0+1\rangle$
represents one single particle in a spin state superposition. On the other hand
$|a\rangle|b\rangle$
is a tensor product, it represents two **distinguishable** particles one of which is in spin state a, the other in spin state b.

Consider now a global measurement we will call "*measurement of the spin population*", this measurement consists in counting the number of atoms in a certain spin state for a given sample. For example

if we consider the separable state  $$|1+0\rangle|1+0\rangle$$ then measuring the spin population in the $|1\rangle$ state will give either 0, 1 or 2, in other words :
$$P_1(|1+0\rangle|0+1\rangle)\in\{0,1,2\}$$
similarly
$$P_0(|1+0\rangle|0+1\rangle)\in\{0,1,2\}$$

If we repeat the measurement a billion times, we will get a certain data histogram, and since there is no particular spin relationship between the two particles, this data will not display any statistical relationship between $P_1$ and $P_0$ (I think).

If we consider now the entangled state $$|1\rangle|3\rangle|3\rangle|0\rangle|0\rangle|0\rangle|0\rangle|0\rangle|0\rangle+|0\rangle|0\rangle|0\rangle|3\rangle|3\rangle|3\rangle|3\rangle|1\rangle|1\rangle$$
then there is a perfect spin relationship between particles **and** if we measure the spin population in state $|1\rangle$ and $|3\rangle$, each time $P_1=1$ we will have $P_3=2$ and each time $P_1=2$ we will have $P_3=4$, and there will be a definite statistical relationship between these global measurements (in our data histogram).

**Question :** Can separable states display statistical correlations between global observables such as $P$ the spin populations, especially for sping greater than 1/2?

Comment: what does the notation $|0+1\rangle$ mean? Is this $|0\rangle+|1\rangle$, or rather a bosonic state such as $|{\rm vac}\rangle+a^\dagger |{\rm vac}\rangle$? Similarly, what does the last equatin represent? Is this a mode occupation list (i.e. $|1\rangle|3\rangle$ means 1 particle in first mode, 3 particles in second mode, etc)?

Comment: I have edited my question, is it clearer ?

Comment: better, but there is still room for improvement I'd say. For example, when you talk of different particles, are your saying that these are *indistinguishable* particles? Because in that case, the state you write at the beginning should really be written (up to normalisation) as $(a_0^\dagger+a_1^\dagger)^2$, which is ket notation amounts to $|20\rangle+|02\rangle+\sqrt2 |11\rangle$. Your $P_0,P_1$ are then what? The number of particles found in first and second mode? In that case, you will definitely find correlations between $P_0$ and $P_1$, as $P_0+P_1=2$ in all cases

Comment: on the other hand, if the particles are distinguishable, then your state is simply $|+,+\rangle$ and there is no need to bother about the particle substrate: you simply have two spin degrees of freedom, and $|+,+\rangle$ is uncontroversially a product (and thus separable) state. But then, it doesn't make sense to say that $P_0$ or $P_1$ can be $2$, does it? Or maybe I should ask: what exactly do you mean with $P_0,P_1$ here?

Comment: they are distinguishable as I jsut clarified, I don't understand you saying that my state is juste $|+,+\rangle$, are you talking about my $|1+0\rangle|1+0\rangle$ state ? it's not the same, each particle is in a superposition of spin states, and a local measurement will give you either 1 or 0 , if you do then a local measurement of the second particle spin, you will have either 1 or 0, in the case where you get 2 times 1, then $P_1=2$, i f you get only one time 1 then $P_1=1$

Comment: ok I think I understand better now. So here $P_i$ is the number of states found in the $i$-th level. With $|+\rangle$ I simply mean the balanced superposition $|0\rangle+|1\rangle$, so this is just another way to write your state. In the two-mode case, you can then write $P_i$ as the observable $P_i=|i\rangle\!\langle i|\otimes I+I\otimes |i\rangle\!\langle i|$. But then, I'd say that there *are* correlations between $P_0$ and $P_1$. For example, $P_0=2$ means you measured in the computational basis and found the particles in $|0,0\rangle$, which means that $P_1=0$

Comment: You have to be careful about what the actual observables in terms of operators here are - unless the observables corresponding to the $P_i$ commute, the phrasing *"each time $P_1$ = 1 we will have $P_3$ = 4"* does not make sense, since there will not be a unique value of $P_i$ for the eigenstate of a $P_j$ with $j\neq i$.

Comment: yes that's it, I should have been more formal from the start. Yes sure for spin half particles this seems obvious, I guess it should remain true for more to some extent for greater spins. @glS

Comment: @ACuriousMind I do not understand, for the state I have written, I think my sentence is correct, the i and j do not refer to particle indices but spin values. for a two particle state Pi=|i⟩⟨i|⊗I+I⊗|i⟩⟨i| as written by glS

Comment: @ACuriousMind while that is of course correct in general, I think in this case it makes sense to talk about them having simultaneous values, as all these observables commute. Practically speaking, you can get the value of all $P_i$ by simply measuring in the computational basis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me reframe the question a bit more precisely.

You have a pure, $n$-qu**d**it state $|\Psi\rangle\in(\mathbb C^d)^{\otimes n}$, where $d$ is the dimension of each individual space (you can actually drop the purity constraint here, it doesn't affect the discussion). In your first example you have $d=2$ and these are qubits, but later you have larger dimensions (seemingly $d=3$). Note that there is no need to talk about particles here, because you are not dealing with the underlying Fock structure (*i.e.* states with different numbers of particles never interact), so it's easier to talk about qubits.

The "spin population measurement" $P_i$ you are talking about are defined as the number of qudits found in the $i$-th level. It's worth stressing that such definition only makes sense if you are measuring in the computational basis, as a question such as "how many qubits are in the up state" only makes sense if your measurement is asking about whether each qubit is up or down.

That said, yes, there are always correlations between the $P_i$. In particular, you always have
$$\sum_{i=1}^d P_i = n.$$
Thus, for example, if $P_1=n$ then $P_j=0$ for $j>1$. These are actually trivial statements if you think about it for a little bit: if each qudit is in the state $|1\rangle$ (*i.e.* $P_1=n$), then obviously there is no qudit in the state $|j\rangle$ for $j>1$.